# Migrating existing Marklogic Application Server from Linux to AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, database-migration, data-migration, marklogic

I'd like to migrate Marklogic 7 Application Server from a Linux environment to AWS.

I've seen pdfs/tutorials on creating a new server on AWS but I'm not sure how to migrate existing data and configurations.

There is more than one cluster.

Thanks
NGala

Answer (score 0):

This question has nothing to do with AWS (AWS servers are just standard Linux servers). Consult your Marklogic documentation on how to migrate between servers.

Answer (score 0):

It makes a big difference whether you need to keep the server online the whole time, or not. If you can shut it down, just install MarkLogic on an AWS linux image and copy `/var/opt/MarkLogic` and any external data directories.

If you need to keep the system online, export a configuration package for your database and app server(s) from the MarkLogic configuration manager on port 8000. Then import it on the new host. Then set up database replication as described at http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/database-replication/dbrep_intro - then once replication has synchronized, fail over to the new system.

Specific to AWS, you could back up a database to S3 from one cluster and then restore it on another cluster. This works even outside AWS, as long as the system can access S3.